# If $f\in C_0$ and $\lambda>0$, how can we show that $x\mapsto\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}f(x(t))\:{\rm d}t$ is continuous wrt the Skorohod topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, skorohod-space

Let $(E,d)$ be a locally compact separable metric space, $C_0(E)$ denote the space of continuous function from $E$ to $\mathbb R$ vanishing at infinity equipped with the supremum norm and $D([0,\infty),E)$ denote the space of càdlàg functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $E$ equipped with the Skorohod topology.

> Let $f\in C_0(E)$ and $\lambda>0$. I want to show that $$D([0,\infty),E)\ni x\mapsto\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}f(x(t))\:{\rm d}t\tag1$$ is bounded and continuous.

It's clear that $(1)$ is bounded, since $f$ is bounded and $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\:{\rm d}t=\frac1\lambda.\tag2$$ How can we show that it is continuous?

**EDIT**: Maybe we need to consider the integral over $[0,T]$ for a fixed $T>0$ in a first step. Let's take a look: Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq D([0,\infty),E)$ and $x\in D([0,\infty),E)$ with $$x_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x\tag3.$$ Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f\in C_0(E)$, $f$ is uniformly continuous and hence there is a $\delta>0$ with $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E\text{ with }d(x,y)<\delta\tag4.$$ By $(3)$, there is a sequence $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of increasing functions mapping $[0,\infty)$ onto $[0,\infty)$ with $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:T]}|\lambda_n(t)-t|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag5$$ and $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:T]}d(x_n(t),x(\lambda_n(t)))\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag6.$$ Thus, there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ with $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:T]}|\lambda_n(t)-t|+\sup_{t\in[0,\:T]}d(x_n(t),x(\lambda_n(t)))<\delta\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N.\tag7$$

> Now we may be able to show that $x$ is "uniformly right-continuous" and write $|f(x_n(t))-f(x(t))|\le|f(x_n(t))-f(x(\lambda_n(t)))|+|f(x(\lambda_n(t)))-f(x(t))|$. The uniform right-continuity seems to be needed for the second term. After that we may write $$\left|\int_0^Te^{-\lambda t}f(x_n(t))\:{\rm d}t-\int_0^Te^{-\lambda t}f(x(t))\:{\rm d}t\right|\le\int_0^Te^{-\lambda t}|f(x_n(t))-f(x(t))|\:{\rm d}t\tag8.$$ How do we need to fill the gaps and proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the Skorokhod topology, a necessary condition for convergence is that $x_n (t) 
\to x(t)$ for all $t$ that are continuity points of $x$.

To prove this assertion, suppose that $x_n \to x$ in the Skorokhod topology. Let $t$ be a continuity point of $x$, take a sequence of time changes $\lambda_n$ as in the definition of convergence in the Skorokhod topology and set $t_n = \lambda_n (t)$. Then $t_n \to t$ and we have

$$d(x_n (t),x(t)) \leq d(x_n(t),x(t_n)) + d(x(t_n),x(t)).$$
Clearly, the first term goes to $0$ by definition of Skorokhod convergence and the second one goes to $0$ because we assumed that $x$ is continuous at $t$.

In particular this means that $x_n \to x$ holds pointwise in a set of full Lebesgue measure, and your first observation on the boundedness allows us to conclude using the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "locally uniformly" here? In order to prevent confusion: The following fact is clear to me: Let $\Lambda_t$ denote the set of increasing functions mapping $[0,t]$ onto $[0,t]$. The Skorohod topology on $D([0,t],E)$ is generated by the metric $$\rho_t(x,y):=\inf_{\lambda\in\Lambda_t}\left(\left\|\lambda-1\right\|_\infty\vee\left\|x-y\circ\lambda\right\|_\infty\right).$$ Now I know that $x_n\to x$ in $D([0,\infty),E)$ is equivalent to $\rho_t(x_n,x)\to0$ for each continuity point $t$ of $x$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @0xbadf00d no, it's not what I mean, though I have to admit that the terminology I am using is not quite clear. I mean that for each $t$ that is a continuity point of $x$ , there is a $\delta > 0$ such that$$\sup_{s\in [t-\delta, t+\delta]} |x_n(s) - x(s)| \to 0$$.

Comment: I upated my answer and provided a simple proof of pointwise convergence at continuity points, which is enough for this question.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. It's not clear what $\lambda_n$ is in your answer.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I edited to give the definition. It is the same thing as in your question.

Comment: How do you define $\left\|x_n\right\|_\infty$? ($E$ is a metric space). The "full Lebesgue measure" conclusion (I guess you mean that the complement is a Lebesgue null set) can be made since $x$ has at most countable many discontinuity points, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93826/discussion-between-user159517-and-0xbadf00d).